# Show count as well as repeated rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to show repeated rows as well count of its duplicate occurrence from mysql table.
For example, we have a table:

```
user_id   course_id 
   01         33
   01         44
   02         55
   02         66
   02         77
```

I want to show results as per below:

```
    user_id   course_id   count
   01         33            02
   01         44            02 
   02         55            03
   02         66            03  
   02         77            03
```

This may be quite a easy query, but i am not getting it right. When i use count(user_id), it asks for group_by else query throws error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

use window function for mysql 8.0 and sql server

```
select *,count(user_id) over()
from table
```

for mysql lower version of 8

```
 select t1.*,( select count(user_id) 
          from table t2 where t1.user_id=t2.user_id) as cunt    
from table t1
```

Comment: Is it for mysql

Comment: @Anjum as you can see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) it is working for mysql version 8

Comment: but unfortunately we have mysql version 5.7.26 and i can not change it from my end on server.